# Error in SQL query with lag windowing function

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I'm working on a [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/rising-temperature/) on Leetcode about SQL. The problem gives a table called `Weather`, with entries for `Id` (as in, id of a temperature measurement), `Temperature`, and `RecordDate`. Each `Id` comes from a subsequent day. They ask for the `Id`s where the temperature that day exceeded the temperature the previous day.

My attempt was

```
select id
    from
        (select id, temperature, lag(temperature, 1) over (ORDER BY RecordDate) prevs
            from weather)
    where temperature > prevs
```

but it tells me there's a syntax error near the `(ORDER BY...` part.

What's wrong?

Comment: Where is MySQL version info? Where is `weather` DDL? *but it tells me there's a syntax error near* Error message must be reproduced as-is, without edition.

Comment: The error you are getting indicates you are on a version of mysql which does not support LAG (ie lower than 8.0) if you were on 8 or above you would get Every derived table must have it's own alias as an error.

Comment: . . .  Please specify the full error message that you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query syntactical incorrect :

First, if you use `LAG()` with position parameter then you must specify the third parameter too. However, by default it is 1. So, don't need to specify :

```
LAG(temperature) over (ORDER BY RecordDate) AS prevs_temp
```

Second, your sub-query doesn't have alias :

```
select t.id
from (select id, temperature, LAG(temperature) over (ORDER BY RecordDate) AS prevs_temp
      from weather
     ) t -- alias missing 
where (t.temperature > t.prevs_temp or t.prevs_temp is null); -- will return id which doesn't have previous `temperature`.
```